# How to filter an array by a child value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i got this object

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "address_components": [
            {
                "long_name": "Abdon Cifuentes - Carlos Silva Vildosola",
                "short_name": "Abdon Cifuentes - Carlos Silva Vildosola",
                "types": [
                    "point_of_interest",
                    "establishment"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Concepción",
                "short_name": "Concepción",
                "types": [
                    "locality",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Concepción",
                "short_name": "Concepción",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_3",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Concepcion",
                "short_name": "Concepcion",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_2",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Región del Bío Bío",
                "short_name": "Región del Bío Bío",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_1",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Chile",
                "short_name": "CL",
                "types": [
                    "country",
                    "political"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "formatted_address": "Abdon Cifuentes - Carlos Silva Vildosola, Concepción, Concepción, Región del Bío Bío, Chile",
        "geometry": {
            "location": {
                "lat": -36.8000307,
                "lng": -73.0487725
            },
            "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport": {
                "northeast": {
                    "lat": -36.7986817197085,
                    "lng": -73.0474235197085
                },
                "southwest": {
                    "lat": -36.8013796802915,
                    "lng": -73.05012148029151
                }
            }
        },
        "place_id": "ChIJxy0y5a61aZYRq9rC4fyIYfg",
        "types": [
            "bus_station",
            "transit_station",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
        ]
    },
    {
        "address_components": [
            {
                "long_name": "Concepción",
                "short_name": "Concepción",
                "types": [
                    "locality",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Concepción",
                "short_name": "Concepción",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_3",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Concepcion",
                "short_name": "Concepcion",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_2",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Región del Bío Bío",
                "short_name": "Región del Bío Bío",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_1",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Chile",
                "short_name": "CL",
                "types": [
                    "country",
                    "political"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "formatted_address": "Concepción, Concepción, Región del Bío Bío, Chile",
        "geometry": {
            "bounds": {
                "northeast": {
                    "lat": -36.76354250000001,
                    "lng": -72.98195799999999
                },
                "southwest": {
                    "lat": -36.8890559,
                    "lng": -73.0841332
                }
            },
            "location": {
                "lat": -36.8201352,
                "lng": -73.0443904
            },
            "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport": {
                "northeast": {
                    "lat": -36.76354250000001,
                    "lng": -72.98195799999999
                },
                "southwest": {
                    "lat": -36.8890559,
                    "lng": -73.0841332
                }
            }
        },
        "place_id": "ChIJO8a70s21aZYRmCYhUrc3y0Q",
        "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
        ]
    }
],
"status": "OK"
}
```

what i need is the function that searchs inside every results[i].types array and if the function find results[i].types[j] == "locality" returns the results[i]. So if results[i].types[j] == "locality" dont find any coincidences, return nothing.

Comment: Actually you have an Object Literal containing Properties holding Arrays.

Comment: Any way to modify the query producing this JSON? That is the easiest way.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan edited, thanks.

Comment: @Wobbles no, the query is already optimized.

Comment: @Wobbles this is a google maps geocode response

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: @charlietfl the second address_componets object. NO! im wrong i need the second array of results !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to narrow down the results  that have a `locality` type

```
var filtered_results = data.results.filter(function(item){
   return item.types.indexOf('locality') >-1;
});
```

Then take the first one from the filtered array

```
var addressParts
if(filtered_results.length){
   addressParts = filtered_components[0].address_components;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but with the first part was enough. !! :)

Answer (score 1):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/bulaxu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

```
console.log( ob.results[1].types )
```

will log this result: `["locality", "political"]`

And notihng inside `formatted_adress` (like you thought) cause that property holds nothing but a string `"Concepción, Concepción, Reg..."`

---

to get the entire `"address_components"` (not stated inside your Question though) use:

```
ob.results[1].address_components
```

---

If you want the entire second object (from your `"results"` array ) use simply:

```
ob.results[1]; // 0 would get the first one, so use 1
```

---

If you want to match the existence of the string `"locality"` inside the `types` Array,  do like

```
var result; // Will hold the entire array if we found "locality" inside the `types` Array

for(var i=0; i<ob.results.length; i++){
  var loc = ob.results[i]; // Iterate all locations
  if(loc.hasOwnProperty("types") && loc.types.indexOf("locality") != -1){
     result = loc;
     break; // Finish iterating once we found the first occurrence
  }
}

console.log( result ); // The 2nd ([1]) array
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/bulaxu/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

Comment: i need to return the ob.results[1]

Comment: @PavelDelgado well... hope the above helped.

Comment: what i need is the function that searchs inside every results[i].types array and if the function find results[i].types[j] == "locality" returns the results[i]